# Code generator help-- Wont stop at sequence I want

Tags: python-3.x

I made a python random sequence generator, I can tell it the max the length of the sequence can be but I want it to stop at a specific sequence... I have spent a couple days searching for a way to do this.

I made the generator do what I want, make a random letter (uppercase and lowercase) and number sequence(I am able to manually change the max it can be) and I made it so It will run forever using a while loop. searched for a couple days to get it the way I want but wont work.

```
import string, random

while True :
    def id_generator(size=2, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + 
string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    if id_generator() == "2g":
        break
        print("found your code")
    else :
        print(id_generator())
```

The "size" makes the max the sequence can be. I wanted the the if statement to say if it creates "2g" to stop and say "found your code" else just keep generating... I think it has something to do with the if statement

Comment: Side note: your `print("found your code")` command will never execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it...

```
import string, random

num = input("Pick your num: ")

while True :
    def id_generator(size=2, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + 
string.digits):
        return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))
    if id_generator() == num:
        print("found your code")
        print(num)
        break
    else :
        print(id_generator())
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't define the function in the while loop. Define it elsewhere and then call it inside the while.

Next, after calling the function assign its value to a variable and let that be used by the conditionals.

Comment: I am a beginner so I don't know  how to call the function... Also can you explain the second part more, I don't understand it.

Comment: defining a function is : ```def function_name(args): ```.

Calling a function is ```function_name(args):```